# выводит такую ошибку помогите -IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range в Unity

Tags: c#

пишу скрипт для unity, на движение колес машины при нажатии на кнопку она должна ехать но при запуске сцены выдаёт неприятную ошибку и я не знаю как это решить.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CarPhisics : MonoBehaviour {

    WheelJoint2D[] wheelJoints;
    JointMotor2D frontWheel;
    JointMotor2D backWheel;

    public float maxSpeed = -1000f;
    private float maxBackSpeed = 1500f;
    private float SpeedBoost = 250f;
    private float deSpeedBoost = -100f;
    public float brakeForce = 3000f;
    private float gravity = 9.8f;
    private float angleCar = 0;

    public ClickScript[] ControlCar;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        wheelJoints = gameObject.GetComponents<WheelJoint2D>();
        backWheel = wheelJoints[1].motor;
        frontWheel = wheelJoints[0].motor;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

        angleCar = transform.localEulerAngles.z;

        if (angleCar >= 180)
        {
            angleCar = angleCar - 360;
        }

        if (ControlCar[0].clikedIs == true) 
        {
            backWheel.motorSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(backWheel.motorSpeed - (SpeedBoost - gravity * Mathf.PI * (angleCar / 180) * 100) * Time.deltaTime, maxSpeed, maxBackSpeed);
        }
        if ((ControlCar[0].clikedIs == false && backWheel.motorSpeed < 0) || (ControlCar[0].clikedIs == false && backWheel.motorSpeed == 0 && angleCar < 0))
        {
            backWheel.motorSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(backWheel.motorSpeed - (deSpeedBoost - gravity * Mathf.PI * (angleCar / 180) * 100) * Time.deltaTime, maxSpeed, 0);          
        }
        else if ((ControlCar[0].clikedIs == false && backWheel.motorSpeed > 0) || (ControlCar[0].clikedIs == false && backWheel.motorSpeed == 0 && angleCar > 0)) 
        {
            backWheel.motorSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(backWheel.motorSpeed - (-deSpeedBoost - gravity * Mathf.PI * (angleCar / 180) * 100) * Time.deltaTime, 0, maxBackSpeed);         
        }

        wheelJoints[1].motor = backWheel;
        wheelJoints[0].motor = frontWheel;
    }
}
```

Выдаёт такую ошибку `IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
CarPhisics.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/scripts/CarPhisics.cs:38)`

Comment: и какая из ваших строчек 38-ая?)

Comment: if (angleCar >= 180)
    {
        angleCar = angleCar - 360;
    } <=== вот эта ковычка

Comment: ControlCar[0] <- наверное тут скорее ошибка, вы задали массив то?

Comment: я иду по курсу одно человека и тут все одинаково как у него

Comment: если хотите могу скинь ссылку на данный урок

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kUivhgdWnU

Comment: Поскольку ошибка не NullPointer, а именно IndexOutOfRange, при обращении к элементу под индексом 0, если я правильно понял, то массив задан, но нулевой длины. Да, на Шарпе, если правильно помню, не будет ошибкой объявить массив нулевой длины! Поищите код инициализации массива, а то тут его не видно

Comment: И да, Вы уж пожалуйста как-то выделите строку, на которой ошибка возникает. Тяжело как-то...

Comment: Очень сильно советую вам начать с основ программирования, узнать что и как работает. После советую найти более грамотного учителя, который учит, а не "школьник рассказывает школьнику как он написал программку добавляя при этом всякие неуместные, матерные высказывания.". Ну а по вопросу, вы серьезно хотите, что бы мы вам помогли с отладкой того, что не видим? Как вы это представляете? У вас ошибка говорит "Ей, ты просишь у меня первый объект из массива, но в нем объектов меньше!", нам от куда знать почему их меньше? Ок, вы сделали то, что сказано в [видео](https://youtu.be/mURFO4K9AS8?t=888)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я глянул видос и нарисовал картинку **как** у вас всё **должно быть**
([в хорошем качестве тут](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1siYh48J2ciaTm2SmYjqVg6CScs4mgeyj/view))**:**

[image]

**Ошибка** *IndexOutOfRangeException* **обозначает то, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу массива, которого нету.** (Если не поняли, что я сейчас написал, то вкратце: массив - набор элементов, в вашем случае набор из ClickScript-объектов. В коде вы, точнее, поц, написавший код, обращается к элементу под номер ноль, но массив, очевидно, пустой, и элемента с номером ноль - нет).

Как я понимаю вы забыли или неправильно перенесли скрипты **"ClickScript"** на объект **"bodyporshe"**, из-за чего **массив**, который используется в коде - **пустой**.

Я видел как автор видео переносил объекты. Что б вам было понятнее, сделайте слегка по другому:

1. В инспекторе (блок справа с информацией) откройте объект **"bodyporshe"** (тоже самое делал и автор видео)
2. В поле с названием **"Size"** напишите без кавычек "2" - это кол-во "ClickScript" (кол-во кнопок)
3. Возле надписи **"Size"** нажмите на треугольник. Выпадет список из 2х прямоугольников
4. Перетащите по-очереди в первый - объект **"Thrt"**, во второй - объект **"Brake"**. Появятся надписи "Thrt(ClickSprite)" и "Brake(ClickSprite)".

После этого данная ошибка в данном массиве невозможна.

.

**Послесловие:**

Люди вверху в комментариях грубы, но всё же правы, говоря то, что нужно начать с основ и потом перейти к курсам. Для начала хотя бы недельку **попрограммируйте вне Unity**. Просто вбейте в гугл "C# курс с нуля". Освойте переменные, массивы, желательно и классы, но тогда, конечно, понадобиться около месяца минимум. Может это  будет не так интересно, ведь основы вам будут показывать в чёрно-белой консольке, но благодаря тому, что это просто консоль, ничто не отвлекает и всё +- понятно.

**После** того, как вы освоите основы, вы **можете** с гордостью **посмотреть курсы по Unity**, но **начинать** всеравно стоит **с простых**, там где попутно будут объяснять интерфейс программы. Напишите пару тройку простых игр и тогда можете делать посложнее, по типу этой.

Да, вы можете и сейчас её написать по урокам этого поца, но вы мало чему научитесь, так как просто копируете код и его действия, не сильно вникая как, что и почему он делает.

.

**Послесловие 2** (если вы ещё **не вникнули** во всё высшесказанное - то лучше даже **не читайте это**, серьёзно)**:**

Я слегка не понял, для чего он сделал массив скриптов для кнопок, можно было явно сделать 2 переменные для кнопки газа и кнопки тормоза. И почему бы не вынести переменные скриптов нажатия в отдельный класс по-типу GameController и просто по нажатию вызывать нужную функцию из скрипта "CarPhisics", заранее заменив его "FixedUpdate" на набор функций. Ну, автору, наверное виднее...